# How does the onPressed voidcallback change the boolean in my function?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

### Situation:

I have a checkbox in one place and i am sending the callback etc. up the widget tree to run a setState and run the function applyFilters().

The NeededChecked is also routed up to the checkbox-value.

### Question:

What i am struggling  to understand is why this works.

**Specifically how the onPressed callback is able to set the value of the bool isNeededState to true/false?**

Here is the code that is run. The only important part is the passing of the bool isNeededState to the neededCheked.

```
 void neededFilterCalled(bool isNeededState) {
    setState(() {
      NeededChecked = isNeededState;
      applyFilters();
    });
}
```

And here is the checkbox widget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Checkbox(
    value: isNeededChecked,
    onChanged: neededFilterCalled,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing

```
onChanged: neededFilterCalled,
```

is shorthand for

```
onChanged: (value) => neededFilterCalled(value),
```

Comment: Oh! And i am guessing the default "value" is a boolean?

Comment: The Checkbox calls this function with true or false, depending if you're checking it or unchecking

Comment: Ok tank you! Will upvote you as soon as i get 2 more rep :D

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged` provide nullable `bool`, defined as

```
required void Function(bool?)? onChanged
```

You can accept null value and provide false on null case like

```dart
  void neededFilterCalled(bool? isNeededState) {
    setState(() {
      isNeededChecked = isNeededState ?? false;
      applyFilters();
    });
  }
```

```dart
return Checkbox(
  value: isNeededChecked,
  onChanged: neededFilterCalled,
);
```